# Conditionally skip a field in yasnippet

Tags: emacs, cobol, yasnippet

I'm trying to create a yasnippet for a MOVE statement i COBOL.
Writing MOVE statements is something we do ALOT of and I want to be as fast and efficient as possible with it.

Usual it is something like this:

```
MOVE variable-1 TO variable-2
```

but sometimes you use functions as well:

```
MOVE FUNCTION LENGTH(variable-1) TO variable-2
```

So what I'm after is a snippet which skips field-2 if field-1 = "FUNCTION".

What I have right now is:

```
MOVE $1 ${2:$$(unless (or yas-modified-p yas-moving-away-p (equal (upcase (yas-field-value 1)) "FUNCTION")) (yas-skip-and-clear-field))} TO $0
```

This works great for the "MOVE FUNCTION ..." case but otherwise it don´t.
Here when I hit  after entered varaible-1 in field-1 i get (cursor is |):

```
MOVE variable-1 #<marker at 2998 in text.cbl>| TO
```

So it seems that the return value from `yas-skip-and-clear-field` get printed instead of doing the jump to $0.

How could I solve this? Or are there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote similar snippet for systemverilog 'logic', whose syntax is:

```
logic MySignal;
```

or

```
logic [31:0] mybus;
```

So ideally, if 'logic' followed by  is typed, the snippet would expand the first field unconditionally. If that field contains [number:number], it expands the other field with name. If [] is not found, the field is considered to be a signal name.

It is not perfect, but here is what I have came with:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: logic
# key: logic
# --
logic ${1:range_or_signal}${2: $(if (string-match "\\[[0-9\s]+:[0-9\s]+\\]" (yas-field-value 1)) (concat " " (string-trim yas-text)) (yas-auto-next ""))};
$0
```

Basically the first field is always entered, and the other one is skipped if first one is not vector definition. The skipping is performed by `yas-auto-next`

Answer (score 1):

If you add `FUNCTION ALL INSTRINSIC` to the `Repository` paragraph in the `Configuration Section`, you need not code `FUNCTION` in your `MOVE` statements.  This might alleviate your problem without having to use yasnippet.

Comment: That is true, but I would prefer not to. Some people in my organization are quite "old fashioned" and prefer the "FUNCTION" prefix. Thanks for the answer!